# Excel: Why is this conditional formatting formula not working?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel spreadsheet (don't ask), with a 4x6 table with headers **Day 1**, **Day 2**, **Day 3**, and **Total**. However, a formula is changing the location of the **Total** according to the date, so at any point **Day 3** could be removed and instead replaced with **Total** if the date detects that we are only up to *Day 2*, so we needn't display headers for *Day 3* yet.

I wanted to use conditional formatting to style everything under **Total** a certain way, so I wrote this formula for the option *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CHAR(COLUMN()+64), 1)) = "Total", TRUE, FALSE)
```

This should be formatting any cell where the cell in its column's first row is equal to "Total". However, it simply never styles anything!

To troubleshoot, I attempted selecting just one column (i.e **C**) and applying a modified form of the rule just to that:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C", 1)) = "Total", TRUE, FALSE)
```

... It worked! Then, I tried simply putting the first formula into a cell, and it was displaying *TRUE* and *FALSE* correctly. Everything seems to work, but for some reason that I could not figure out the conditional formatting would never apply.

Can someone please explain why?

*PS in the question I wrote a simplified example, in the real thing I have 31 days instead of three, so it would be a major hassle to go through each column individually*

Comment: indirect shouldn't be used in named ranges or conditional formatting rules. try `=column(a1)=match("total", row(1:1), 0)` as a cfr formula with a refersto of A:C.

Comment: Does `...CONCATENATE(C,1)...` work? You don' have to do `...(C:C,1)...`?  Also, check the `Applies To` range of your conditional format to make sure the range matches the formula/expected formatting.

Comment: BruceWayne - Sorry, that was a mistake; it was meant to say `CONCATENATE("C", 1)`, but I missed out the speech marks.

Comment: @Jeeped - sorry, but that didn't seem to work for me. It is still having no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CHAR(COLUMN()+64), 1))` is probably the worst possible way I can think of to reference the cell in the first row and same column.

Instead of this:

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CHAR(COLUMN()+64), 1)) = "Total"
```

Try this (for example, for a conditional formatting rule in the `A` column, and apply the rule where ever else you need it):

```
A$1 = "Total"
```

These two formulas have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I solved this myself. Turns out that my formula was fully correct, but for some strange reason it didn't like the IF statement; I replaced it with:

```
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CHAR(COLUMN()+64), 1)) = "Total"
```

and it works fine!

However, I would still appreciate it if someone could explain why this happened (for future reference)